# Enlazar HTML y App Escritorio con base de datos en maquina virtual

Tags: html, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente duda, actualmente tengo una Maquina virtual en Azure, a la cual configure para que sea el host de una pagina web, seguidamente me gustaría crear una base de datos en esa maquina virtual, y poder vincularla con la pagina WEB, sin embargo siempre veo en YouTube que las bases de datos las hacen localhost y las vinculan con localhost, entonces no se si al hacer el enlace de HTML con la base localhost de mi maquina valla a funcionar para que las personas que ingresen a mi pagina puedan guardar datos en la base de datos.

Entonces la pregunta es si ¿De esta manera funcionaria, o se debe hacer de otra forma?

Es que también me gustaría crear aplicaciones de escritorio que se puedan vincular a esa base de datos, pero al ser local host supongo que ha de necesitar una IP para ello.

Comment: En mi vida he visto enlazar HTML con una base de datos, sinceramente. HTML es un lenguaje estático que lo único que hace es mostrar cosas en pantalla. No tiene lógica, y desde luego no tiene conectores con bases de datos. PHP y JavaScript si tienen capacidad para conectarse con bases de datos, y da igual que la página esté en localhost o donde quieras, si tu pc tiene internet podrá conectarse a tu base de datos, esté donde esté, siempre que tenga acceso a la red, claro

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que soy nuevo en esto de la programación web y tenia esa duda, puesto que no estaba seguro y no sabia ni siquiera por donde empezar a buscar en internet. pd: con razón al buscar conectar HTML con base de datos no me salía nada jajajaja